# Cast exception converting Json string to DBObject (Scala/Mongo)

Tags: json, mongodb, scala

I am facing one issue but it occurs randomly any time not always. I am not sure what is the issue.

What I am trying is I have an JSON string and I am converting it to DBObject and then push/insert it to mongo DB. below is the code for same.
Here final_json_str is JSON string which I am reading it from input file and then converting it to DBOject and then inserting it to Mongo DB.

```
val dbObject: DBObject = JSON.parse(final_json_str).asInstanceOf[DBObject]
```

But some time I am getting error as CastClassException cannot convert java.lang.String to com.mongodb.DBObject.

Can anyone one help me, Am i doing some thing wrong in this. Please let me know if more details are required.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: It looks like your `JSON.parse` method returns a `String`, which is kinda weird. What library are you using to parse JSON?

Comment: I am using this lib import com.mongodb.util.JSON

Comment: If on the 3.x version of the driver, I would suggest updating to use the new `Document` class in the 3.x version of the driver and `Document.parse(json)`.  However, there is also a `BasicDBObject.parse(json)` method.

Answer (score 0):

from the signature of JSON.parse

```
public static Object parse(final String jsonString)
```

One can see it can actually return any Object. Looking a bit further in the actual code, the parse will choose what method to return with a big switch on the first character of your String.

In the case it matches either ' or " the returned Object will be a String which you try to cast into a DBObject.